# Ursina Unicode Display

Tags: text, unicode, entity, ursina

When i try to paste in a Unicode in The Text Entity as a text. it comes up with the error:

```
:text(warning): No definition in  for character U+21d5
```

I have also tried to use the Unicode string itself inside the text string.
Anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Do you mean character `⇕` (U+21D5,  *Up Down Double Arrow*)? I'd look for a suitable font (e.g. `DejaVu`, `Cambria`, `Segoe UI` or `Unifont`) …

Answer (score 0):

See https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/issues/523

you need a font that supports unicode like https://github.com/multitheftauto/unifont/releases